# XPath with java: retrieving text from an element including text form children

Tags: xpath

I have a following sequence of tags.

```
<div id="article-entry">
<p>
This is a paragraph for text extraction using  
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/">xpath</a>
.
</p>
```

I would like to retrieve following text from tags using xpath.

> This is a paragraph for text extraction using xpath.

I have tried following case:

> /div[@id='article-entry']/p/text()
>
> /div[@id='article-entry']/p[//a/text()]/text()
>
> /div[@id='article-entry']/p[text() or //a/text()]/text()
>
> /div[@id='article-entry']/p[concat(text(),//a/text())]/text()

the output from these is:

> This is a paragraph for text extraction using

can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can normalize the result of the `string()` core function, supplied with a node-set argument.

The way `string()` function works, it will take the first node in document order from the node set in argument and convert it to a string, by obtaining the node's string-value, which is a concatenation of all text node descendants in document order for element nodes per XPath specification.

`normalize-space()` function returns the argument string with whitespace normalized by stripping leading and trailing whitespace and replacing sequences of whitespace characters by a single space.

```xml
normalize-space(string(//div[@id='article-entry']/p))
```

Result of this query is:

```xml
'This is a paragraph for text extraction using xpath .'
```

Close enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
string(//div[@id='article-entry']/p)
```

Or you maybe able to just stop at `<p>` level then use [`getTextContent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29) :

```
//div[@id='article-entry']/p
```

Comment: Thanks @har07. string() core function worked in my case.